# Does Spark Streaming provide a guarantee on the order of the date when reducing

Tags: apache-spark, reduce, spark-streaming

I was wondering if when calling reduceByKey in apache spark streaming the order of the records in the stream were guarantied. Basically part of the computation I do has to get the last value.

Here's an example:

```
JavaPairDStream< String, Double >  pairs; // ...
pairs.reduceByKey( new Function2<Double, Double, Double>() { 
            @Override public Double call(Double first, Double second) throws Exception { 
                return second;
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't. The intention of Map Reduce is to parallize tasks and when parallized you cannot guarantee order. The previous results might get shuffled on the way to the reduce processor. Note that the reduce processor won't wait for all results to arrive, he justs grabs two values and starts reducing.

> Once created, the distributed dataset (distData) can be operated on in parallel. For example, we might call distData.reduce((a, b) => a + b) to add up the elements of the array.

Comment: How sad! I guess I don't really need the last value.

Comment: @jules: If you describe your use case in a followup question maybe we could suggest an alternative. Notify me if you create another question.